# what we cannot inherit from a Base class : why?

Tags: c++, inheritance

After the end of my first C++ course, I have some questions that I'd like to clarify for myself.

We cannot inherit the following (C++ standard won't allow):
    constructor, copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor.
    So, if we have:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class A
    {
    public:
        A() {cout << "CTOR of A" << endl;}
        ~A() {cout << "DTOR of A" << endl;}
        A (const A &) {cout << "Cctor of A" << endl;}
        A& operator =(const A& other) {/* some code */}
    };

    class B : public A
    {
        /* B's data members and methods */
    };

    int main()
    {
        /* code */
        return 0;
    }
```

class `B` won't inherit all four, but why? For the constructor - I
think that if `B` would inherit `A`'s constructor, then instead of
creating a larger object (a `B` object, because B inherits from A,
then it would be a larger object) we'd create a smaller one, without
`B`'s methods and data-members. Am I right or wrong?

What about the destructor, copy constructor and assignment operator?
Does the reason above (assuming it is correct) apply for them also?

Regards
Ron

Comment: You do inherit the assignment operator

Comment: you are asking a few different things. Please ask them as different questions.

Comment: You do inherit the assignment operator, but the subclass has its own assignment operator as well.  Standard rules for name lookup thus mean that you always find the derived class version instead of the base class version.

Comment: As a vaguely unrelated comment, friends are also not inherited.

Comment: In a way, you do inherit constructors as well. Example: `class B: public A { B() { do_something(); } };` The constructor `B::B()` will call `A::A()` even though you didn't tell it to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple inheritance is one reason that you don't inherit constructors.  Copy constructors are not special in this respect.

```
struct B1 {
  virtual ~B1() {}
  B1(int a);
};

struct B2 {
  virtual ~B2() {}
  B2(int a);
};

struct D : public B1, public B2 {
};
```

It isn't clear which one would be appropriate in this case.

I personally believe implementation intent is more clear by not inheriting them as well, though that may not be a reason that a language designer would state.

You can and always should define a destructor virtual if you intend to inherit from it.

```
class A {
public:
  virtual ~A() {cout << "DTOR of A" << endl;
};
```

Without the virtual you will memory leak.

As noted by others, assignment operators will be inherited.  I have a sneaking suspicion that the usefulness of an inherited assignment operator would be limited though.

Edit:

Upon further reading, the non-virtual destructor is actually undefined behavior.  In practice, it just shows up as memory leak.

Comment: I didn't mean virtual destructors ,I've no problems with that concept(i.e. virtual destructors for preventing memory leaks).I meant something else , that if we have two classes A and B , then B would inherit B's dtor ... this is of course is not possible .I just did not get exactly the reason ...thanks :)

Comment: @Ron_s Did you mean "then A would inherit B's dtor"?

Comment: @Ron_s The same concept applies as the ctors.  With multiple inheritance, a dtor would be ambiguous.

Comment: Yes ,of course. I'm sorry . Editing : A would inherit B's destructor , i.e. : class A : public B {  /* code */ }

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are not inherited. Everything else is. Think of it like that: inheritance is a special case of aggregation. I.e. your example is equal to

```
class A
{
...
}

class B
{
public:
  A a;
}
```

Here `A` retains all of its properties, but it doesn't provide constructors for B. Same happens when you do inheritance, expect that you don't need to specify `a` to address the content of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way: B is a specialised type of A. (B is not exactly A.) So, B might have a few more data members, which also need to be created/destroyed. This is not possible by using A's ctor, dtor etc. Or, even if B does not have any more data members, it might do the construction/destruction in a different way.

Derived classes are specialised versions of base classes, thus needing their own ctor/dtor.